# Measurability of an inner product-like function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}:= \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{R}$ together with the product (Borel) $\sigma$-algebra $B(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}})$. We define $$s := \bigcap_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}s_{m} \quad \mbox{and} \quad s' :=\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}s_{m},$$ where, for each $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $s_{m}:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}, \hspace{0.1cm} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}n^{2m}|x_{n}|^{2} <\infty\}$. If $x \in s$ is fixed, define a function $f$ from $s'$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by $f(y) = \langle y,x\rangle := \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}y_{i}x_{i}$. I want to prove that $f$ is a measurable function. My reasoning is as follows.

It suffices to prove that every set of the form $(-\infty,a)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, since these sets generate the borel $\sigma$-algebra $B(\mathbb{R})$. Now, I know that $s'$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and I'm assuming I should take the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{s'}:= \{s'\cap E, \hspace{0.1cm} E \in B(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}})\}$. It is easy to prove that the projection map $s'\ni x \mapsto x_{k}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{s'}$-measurable. So, the set $$A_{N} = \{y\in s', \hspace{0.1cm} \sum_{i=1}^{N}y_{i}x_{i}<a\}$$ is $\mathcal{F}_{s'}$-measurable for each fixed $N$, since it is the sum of products of projection maps with scalars (the components of $x$). Thus, $A_{N}$ being measurable, we have $$f^{-1}((-\infty,a)) = \bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}A_{N}$$ which is measurable because it is the countable intersection of measurable sets.

Is my reasoning right? Did I do anything wrong?